# Azure DevOps Organization setup with cost at project level

Tags: azure-devops

I want to setup Azure DevOps organization wide. For that, we have decided that we will set up a single Azure DevOps organization and every team will work underneath this organization as separate project. The only challenge which I am getting is to determine the cost incurred by each project. Azure DevOps generates bill at organization level however we want to know how much a specific project incurred cost so that we can charge that team accordingly. I am not so much aware about azure devops billing prospects. Any insight would be very useful to me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question seems to be too broad and requires us to study much of azure-devops to answer the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to set unique custom tags, using the same per each specific project. Then from there you should be able to have cost propects based on tags specified by grouping on tags [1].

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management/quick-acm-cost-analysis

Comment: Thanks Federico, I know there is as such no direct way to determine the cost incurred on specific projects. However, using unique custom tags, I can somehow move towards that. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: Happy it helped you out Joe, if you can mark this answer as accepted that may be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to determine the cost incurred by each project, As you know the [paid services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fsecurity-access-billing%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fsecurity-access-billing%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#all-services-are-billed-via-azure)(eg, paid basic access for users, paid ci/cd, paid test plan, etc) in azure devops are billed at organization level.

You can [submit a suggest](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) for such feature to be developed. Hopefully the development team will consider it and develop this feature.

You may have to manually calculate the paid resources(paid users, ci/cd(I found the [build usage](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.BuildandTestUsage) extension can be used to analyze ci/cd cost), paid test plans) that used by each project, and calculate a rough cost until the cost view for each project is developed.